# A Circle Problem

Tags: geometry, circles

A circle $K$, a tangent $T$ and a point $A$ on $t$ are given. Find the locus of all point $X$ for which points $Y$ and $Z$ on $T$ exist which are equidistant from $A$ and make $K$ the incircle of the triangle $XYZ.$

I suppose that the locus of all point $X$ is a straight but I can't prove it.
I hope you can give me suggestions or hints for my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What are points $P,Q,R$? Did you mean triangle $XYZ$?

Comment: Ohh yes sry ;). I read it out from the wrong line ;). I have to exercise for an exam and so I have got a lot of exercises ;).

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be the tangency point, and let $B'$ be a point symmetric to this point in point $A$. Also let $P$ be a point antipodal to $B$ on $K$. Now $B'$ is a point of tangency of excircle of triangle $XYZ$ opposite to vertex $X$. Now it's easy to see that a homothety taking the incircle to excircle with center at $X$ moves $P$ to $B'$, which means that $X,P,B'$ are collinear, so $X$ lies on line $PB'$. You should also be able to show that in order for $XYZ$ to have K as an incircle we need $X$ to lie on an open ray contained in line $PB'$ with one end at $P$ and *not* containing $B'$ (in some other cases we can make K be an excircle, but not an incircle).

To show that every point $X$ on this ray satisfies the requirement, take two tangents to K passing through $X$ and call intersections of these tangents with line t $Y$ and $Z$. By using arguments similar to above we can show that $Y,Z$ are equidistant from $A$.

[image]

Edit: here is why $P$ moves to $B'$: Let me denote the excircle by E here. Note that the line tangent to K at $P$ is parallel to line t. Because image of line under a homothety is parallel to original line, we get that image if this tangent is parallel (or equal to) line t. But this image will also be tangent to E (because E is the image of K). I hope it's clear enough why image of this tangent to K must then be t. Lastly, the image of tangency point is a tangency point, so image of $P$ will be tangency point of E to t, which is precisely $B'$.

Comment: Thank for helping me. I have got one question. Why does $P$ move to $B'$? You only said that $P$ is the antipodal to $B$.

Comment: What's about the case if $Y$ is on $B$ or $Y$ is very close to $B$? The straight $XY$ and the straight $XZ$ would be parallel and then they were cutting each other on the opposite site $X$.

Comment: @grok, I have added an argument why image of $P$ must be $B'$.

Comment: @grok I don't really understand your second comment. It's impossible for $XY$ and $XZ$ to be parallel, as they are always distinct lines, and they have common point $X$.

Comment: ahh ok I understood. thank you very much for your very quick solution ;).